# C++ ifstream error using string as opening file path.

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have:

```
string filename: 
ifstream file(filename);
```

The compilers complains about no match between ifstream file and a string. Do I need to convert filename to something?

Here's the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::string&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:454: note: candidates are: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Comment: I'm sure you could improve the title of this question.

Comment: I changed it to ifstream error.

Comment: That's still incredibly vague. Can't you make it so that it actually describes the specific issue?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Change

```
ifstream file(filename);
```

to

```
ifstream file(filename.c_str());
```

Because the constructor for an `ifstream` takes a `const char*`, not a `string` pre-C++11.

Comment: "love" c++ so much!

Answer (score 11):

The `ifstream` constructor expects a `const char*`, so you need to do `ifstream file(filename.c_str());` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

in c++-11 it can also be an std::string. So (installing c++-11 and) changing the dialect of you project to c++-11 could also fix the problem.

Comment: while your answer is correct, it is already present in the accepted answer, although not so clearly: `not a string pre-C++11.`